# Converting CERTCertificate derCert to SECKEYPublicKey

Tags: c++, nss

I'm using C++ with nss and nspr libraries on 64 bit Ubuntu Linux and am trying to convert CERTCertificate derCert to SECKEYPublicKey but SECKEY_ImportDERPublicKey keeps returning -8183:

Security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message.

I have also tried to use SECKEY_ImportDERPublicKey with CERTCertificate derPublicKey but I got the same response.

Which function pair should be used for derCert and which for derPublicKey conversion to SECItem and back to SECKEYPublicKey or CERTCertificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question...

CERTCertificate contains two member variables derCert and derPublicKey (both of type SECItem) that I was interested in.

### Save/Load public key

To get the public key you can either save CERTCertificate derPublicKey value or get the same value from SECKEYPublicKey:

```
// cert is of type CERTCertificate
SECKEYPublicKey* publicKey = CERT_ExtractPublicKey( cert );
SECItem* derPublicKey = SECKEY_EncodeDERSubjectPublicKeyInfo( publicKey );
// put the key into string
std::string keyString( (char*)derPublicKey->data, derPublicKey->len );
```

To decode the public key from string you use:

```
SECItem derKeyItem = {
        .type = siBuffer,
        .data = (unsigned char*)keyString.c_str(),
        .len = (unsigned int)keyString.size()
    };
CERTSubjectPublicKeyInfo* pubInf = SECKEY_DecodeDERSubjectPublicKeyInfo( &derKeyItem );
SECKEYPublicKey* publicKey = SECKEY_ExtractPublicKey( pubInf );
```

### Save/Load certificate and get public key

To save certificate you save derCert.

To load certificate and get public key:

```
SECItem derCertItem = {
        .type = siBuffer,
        .data = (unsigned char*)certStr.c_str(),
        .len = (unsigned int)certStr.size()
    };
CERTCertificate cert = CERT_NewTempCertificate(CERT_GetDefaultCertDB(), &derCertItem, nullptr, false, false);
SECKEYPublicKey* publicKey = CERT_ExtractPublicKey(cert);
```

### Note

The above code is sample code. For production code smart pointers (unique/shared) should be used and their destructors should call the appropriate nss destroy functions.